# ngmin not working in windows

Tags: windows, angularjs, minify

I am trying to minify all js files (start with controllers and app.js). As we know that regular minifier (uglify etc) won't work directly on angularjs files because of module declaration conventions.
So I tried using ngmin for that.
Concatenated all files and then tried using ngmin - but get this error ...

```
C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngmin\node_modules\esprima\espri
ma.js:3872
            throw e;
                  ^
Error: Line 1007: Unexpected token *
    at throwError (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngmin\node_mo
dules\esprima\esprima.js:1156:21)
    at throwUnexpected (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngmin\no
de_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1213:9)
    at parsePrimaryExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\n
gmin\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1567:16)
    at parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\ngmin\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1644:61)
    at parsePostfixExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\n
gmin\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1703:20)
    at parseUnaryExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngm
in\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1784:16)
    at parseMultiplicativeExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\ngmin\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1790:20)
    at parseAdditiveExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
ngmin\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1807:20)
    at parseShiftExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ngm
in\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1824:20)
    at parseRelationalExpression (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\ngmin\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:1845:16)
```

I believe the issue is related to running ngmin in windows environment. I shall try it again with Mac - but trying to gauge if anybody faced this issue and able to find any work-around ?
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be related to concatenating. It's most likely not a Windows issue (I've run `ngmin` on Windows just fine). There's an open issue for this: https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin/issues/12.

I know the recommendation is to run it once on a concatenated file, but you might want to try running `ngmin` prior to concatenation and see what happens. If that ends up fine, try to concatenate afterwards.

Comment: Thanks - will try that as later I had same issue in mac also

Comment: Interesting!
Here are the steps that I had to follow to make it work:

1. ngmin each .js file separately

2. uglify each file 

3. Concat everything in one file

4. Finally delete a zero length char from end of the concatenated file 

After all these it worked at least for controllers. Will try with services and directives now :)

Comment: @pagladasu good to hear. I'm in the process of setting up our Grunt build at work. I haven't gotten as far as concatenating so haven't run into this issue just yet. Keep us posted :)